# Incrementally Computing $\Sigma_t v_t$ Without Storing $x_i$, $v_i$, or $\Sigma_t$

Tags: covariance-matrix, online-algorithms

Motivation: I have a discussion with friends many days ago, at that time I think this problem is very easy so we directly skip, later I realize I cannot solve it XD. The problem is:

Given a sequence of vectors $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_t$ and $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$ in an online fashion, I'm interested in computing the product of the sum of outer products $\Sigma_t$ with $v_t$, where
$$
\Sigma_t=\sum_{i=1}^t x_i x_i^T
$$

Specifically, the term of interest is $\Sigma_t v_t$.

However, there are constraints for memory (only O(p)):

1. I cannot store all individual vectors $x_i$ or $v_i$ for $i<t$. Finite them is ok.
2. I cannot store the matrix $\Sigma_t$.
3. The vector $v_i$ can change from one time step to the next.

Given these constraints, is there a way to compute $\Sigma_t v_t$ incrementally as each new $x_t$ and $v_t$ arrives?

I'm looking for an efficient approach that uses minimal storage and captures the effect of the changing $v_t$ without explicitly storing past data or the matrix sum. Any suggestions, insights, or relevant literature would be greatly appreciated!

When $v_t$ is unchanged over time, we definitely have a solution by introduce some ancillary variables. But I fail for the varying $v_t$ case.

Comment: $\Sigma_t$ seems to be a $t\times t$ matrix. So for $\Sigma_tv_t$ to make sense, $v_t$ should be a vector of length $t$, no? Specifically, the sequence $(v_t)$ needs to consist of vectors of increasing length: $v_1\in\mathbb{R}^1$, $v_2\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and so forth.

Comment: ... in which case the question of course is whether $v_t$ is just $v_{t-1}$, to which we concatenate a new $t$-th component, or some completely new vector. In the latter case, you will likely at least need to store $v_{t-1}$ for an online algorithm (though probably not $v_1, \dots, v_{t-2}$).

Comment: What *can* you store??

Comment: both $x_t,v_t$ are p dimensional vector, $\Sigma_t $ is positive semidefinite matrix with dimension p by p. If we can store $v_t$ and $v_{t-1}$, it is ok because store 2p, 3p, 4p are just constant times p, they are all $O(p)$, but even we store finite them, it seems still not work if I do not store all of them.

Comment: I modify the constraint 1, but this is still quite ideal, maybe impossible...

Answer (score 2):

You ask how to perform a sequential update of the vector sequence

$$\sigma_n = \sum_{t=1}^n \Sigma_t v_t = \sum_{t=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^t x_i x_i^\prime \, v_t.$$

To update $\sigma_n$ to $\sigma_{n+1}$ you will add their difference,

$$\sigma_{n+1} - \sigma_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i x_i^\prime v_{n+1} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^\prime\right)v_{n+1} + x_{n+1}\left(x_{n+1}^\prime v_{n+1}\right).\tag{*}$$

Consequently, if you maintain a data structure that includes

$$A_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^\prime$$

which (because it is symmetric) requires storing only $p(p+1)/2$ coefficients, then the total storage for all variables in the update is $p(p+1)/2$ (for $A_n$) plus $p$ (for $\sigma_n$) plus $2p$ (for $x_{n+1}$ and $v_{n+1}$ plus $1$ (for accumulating $x_{n+1}^\prime v_{n+1}$), summing to $p^2/2 + 7p/2 + 1 = O(p^2).$

*This is the best you can possibly do,* because clearly the update depends on $A_n$ and if you don't store full information about it, then for sufficiently large $p$ you can construct an alternative matrix $B_n$ that yields the same value of your data structure but a different value of $B_n v_{n+1}$ for some nonzero possible value of $v_{n+1}.$

---

To show this is not mere speculation or opinion, I will offer a definite statement and a proof.

**Proposition.** Let the available storage asymptotically be less than $O(p^2)$ and suppose you can store piecewise differentiable functions of the data (which is all you can do in standard models of computing).  Then there exists a $p$ for which you cannot sequentially update $\sigma_n$ forever.

**Proof.** The assumptions imply the set of possible values you can store are at most a countable union of differentiable manifolds (possibly with boundaries and corners).  Let the largest dimension of any component of this union be $d(p).$  We have supposed that for any number $\lambda \gt 0,$ there exists a sufficiently large $p$ for which $d(p) \lt \lambda p^2.$

Formula $(*)$ shows that $\sigma_n$ can be updated with $O(p)$ storage plus the amount of storage required to compute $A_n v_{n+1}$ *for arbitrary vectors $v_{n+1}$.*  In other words, *any* possible updating algorithm will be capable of computing every possible $A_n v_{n+1}$ with at most $O(p)$ extra storage.  The map $v\to A_n V$ defines a symmetric endomorphism of $\mathbb R^p.$  The set of such transformations is a differentiable submanifold of $\mathbb R^{p^2}$ of dimension $p(p+1)/2.$   Applying the first observation to the case $\lambda = 1/2$ shows we cannot store every possible element in this set, implying it is not possible to update $\sigma_n$ with certainty for all $n$ with this value of $p,$ *qed.*

Comment: Thanks whuber, I agree this one should be the best we can possibly do.